# Call a javascript function that's a member of an object by name

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to pass a reference to an arbitrary function by name to another javascript function. If it's just a global function, there is no problem:

```
function runFunction(funcName) {
   window[funcName]();
}
```

But suppose the function could be a member of an arbitrary object, e.g.:

```
object.property.somefunction = function() {
 //
}
```

`runFunction("object.property.somefunction")` does not work. I know I can do this:

`window["object"]["property"]["somefunction"]()`

So while could write code to parse a string and figure out the heirarchy this way, that seems like work :) So I wondered if there's any better way to go about this, other than using `eval()`

Comment: Why do you need this? What's wrong with calling the function directly? It seems needlessly complicated.

Comment: @Cfreak: That depends on what his strings come from.

Comment: The function name is coming from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope -- other than using `eval` I do not know another way of walking down an object tree in JavaScript than to build a walker -- fortunately, it is easy to do:

```
/**
* Walks down an object tree following a provided path. 
* Throws an error if the path is invalid.
* 
* @argument obj {Object} The object to walk.
* @argument path {String} The path to walk down the provided object.
* @argument return_container {Boolean} Should walk return the last node *before* the tip 
* (i.e my_object.my_node.my_other_node.my_last_node.my_attribute)
* If `true` `my_last_node` will be returned, rather than the value for `my_attribute`.
* @returns {Mixed} Object or the value of the last attribute in the path.
*/
function walk_path(obj, path, return_container) {
    return_container = return_container || false;
    path = path_to_array(path, ".");
    var ln = path.length - 1, i = 0;
    while ( i < ln ) {
        if (typeof obj[path[i]] === 'undefined') {
            var err = new ReferenceError("The path " + path.join(".") + " failed at " + path[i] + ".");
            err.valid_path = path.slice(0,i);
            err.invalid_path = path.slice(i, ln+1);
            err.breaking_point = path[i];
            throw err;
        } else {
            var container = obj;
            obj = obj[path[i]];
            i++;
        }
    }
    // If we get down to the leaf node without errors let's return what was asked for.
    return return_container ? container : obj[path[i]];
};

/**
* path_to_array
*
* @argument path {string} A path in one of the following formats:
* `path/to/file`
* `path\\to\\file`
* `path.to.file`
* `path to file`
* @argument sep {string} optional A seperator for the path. (i.e. "/", ".", "---", etc.)
*
* If `sep` is not specified the function will use the first seperator it comes across as the path seperator.
* The precedence is "/" then "\\" then "." and defaults to " "
*
* returns {Array} An array of each of the elements in the string ["path", "to", "file"]
*/
function path_to_array(path, sep) {
    path = is_string(path) ? path : path + "";
    sep = is_string(sep) ? sep : 
                path.indexOf("/") >= 0 ? "/" : 
                path.indexOf("\\") >= 0 ? "\\" : 
                path.indexOf(".") >= 0 ? "." : " ";
    /* Alternately use SLak's
    sep = is_string(sep) ? sep : /[ \\/.]/;
    if you want simpler code that will split on *any* of the
    delimiters by default. */
    return path.split(sep);
}

function is_string(s) { return typeof s === "string"; }
```

Then just call it like so:

```
walk_path(my_object, "path.to.my.function")();
```

Comment: Yes, I already had the code available ... and yes, this is the *enterprise* version of @SLaks code. ;-)

Comment: Why don't you split on `/[\\/.]/`?

Comment: So much better than reinventing the wheel! Perfect.

Comment: @SLaks -- two reasons -- first, I forgot that string.split took a regular expression :-D -- second, simply because the function in question was also used to split things that might contain another of the characters as a seperator `path/to/some.resource/query.information` for example.  But that could be handled by the `sep` code, now couldn't it?  Thanks!

Comment: For completeness, this is missing a function `is_string`. I can figure that part out though.

Answer (score 7):

You can call `funcName.split('.')` and loop through the resulting array, like this:

```
function runFunction(funcName) {
    var parts = funcName.split('.');
    var obj = window;

    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++)
        obj = obj[parts[i]];

    return obj();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as possible avoid using `eval()` when you have a choice.

In your case you can split the param based on `'.'` and then construct your

```
window["object"]["property"]["somefunction"]()
```

Comment: You just restated his question.

Comment: @SLaks - I think yes, on the part where the OP needs to avoid eval(). Other than that I have suggested him to split based on '.', but you have already given complete answer anyway ;). I was more thinking on lines of `window[array[0]][array[1]][array[2]]()`